# Why is this bit function returning in reverse order?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a variable called "bitarray" which is an array of 'unsigned long' types. This is initially all zeros in binary format.

```
0000000000000000000000000000000
```

I use a mask to change this to a different number.

```
mask = 0x1FFFFFF; 
bitarray[n] = bitarray[n] ^ mask; 
printBinary(bitarray[n]);
```

Result:

```
0000000111111111111111111111111
```

Then I use bit shifting to check the value of each bit and print out what it's set to.

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<31; i++) {   
    if((val>>i) & 1)  {
        printf("1");
    } else {
        printf("0");
    }
}
```

The problem is this prints in the exact opposite order:

```
1111111111111111111111111000000
```

My goal is just to be able to check whether a bit is set.

Comment: Look at your code and think.

Comment: The code is returning the proper bit. You just need to ask for them in the reverse order. Which bit do you want to print first?

Comment: I want to check the left-most bit first.

Comment: You want to check the MOST SIGNIFICANT BIT first... but when you do `val >> 0`, you are checking the LEAST SIGNIFICANT BIT...  Like Walz said, look at your code and ***think***.

Answer (score 1):

You want to print the most significant bit first.  Maybe try something like this:

```
int i;
for(i=31; i>=0; i--) 
    printf("%d", (val>>i) & 1);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: 2 answers in the same second!

Answer (score 1):

Switch for loop order

```
// for(i=0; i<31; i++) { 
for(i=31; i >= 0; i--) {
```